# CakePHP 2 HTMLHelper link

Tags: php, cakephp-2.5

I try to write a link which ends in this:

```
<a href="#">Text</a>
```

How have I to change this code?

```
echo $this->Html->link('Text', array('url' => '#'));
```

The above code ends in something like this:

```
<a href="/accounting/vouchers/uploads/url:%23">Text</a>
```

Unfortunately, there is the controller and the action with url as parameter.

Comment: Just echo the link directly, in this case there is no reason to use the CakePHP HTML Helper to generate the link...

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Text', '#');
```